# how to configure swagger with nestjs/graphql projects

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, nestjs-swagger, nestjs-graphql

I'm working on a project using NestJS and GraphQL, and I want to add Swagger documentation to my API endpoints. I have already set up GraphQL and it's working fine, but I'm not sure how to configure Swagger to generate the documentation for my GraphQL API.

I've looked through the NestJS documentation and some online tutorials, but most of them focus on REST APIs with Swagger. I couldn't find a clear example or guide on how to integrate Swagger with a NestJS project using GraphQL.

Can anyone provide step-by-step instructions or point me to a resource that explains how to configure Swagger with NestJS and GraphQL? I want to be able to document my GraphQL schema, types, queries, and mutations using Swagger so that it's easier for other developers to understand and test my API.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to add swagger to your GraphQL endpoints? Part of the draw of GraphQL is not needing the swagger, because the GraphQL schema _is_ the documentation

Comment: @JayMcDoniel yes you are right, we have graphql Playground.